# Why was this question closed? Should it be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently found this question via a Google search: [How can I decompress an archive file having tar.zst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355277/how-can-i-decompress-an-archive-file-having-tar-zst)

I had the exact same question, and the answers were helpful.  I am very technical, but I had never heard of the `zstd` before this search/question/answer.

I see the question was asked in 2017, then closed.  Why was this question closed?  And, should it be re-opened?  Sure, the question could be cleaned up to meet current standards, but the answers are very helpful.  Thoughts?

Comment: How is that a programming task? Or more specific: a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: Being closed didn't prevent you finding it. Opening it won't improve it's search ability. On the other hand opening it exposes other people to ask why their question was closed and using this one as example of one that is off-topic but open

Comment: i am thiniknh about deleting the question as it  is the lowest quality question i came across for some days

Comment: @charlietfl Very helpful.  Thank you to explain.

Answer (score 23):

Whether answers are very helpful isn't a criterion for re-opening off-topic questions. If someone sneaks in a question about making apple pie and Gordon Ramsay posts an answer I'm sure that answer is useful. Unfortunately we just turned into Stack Overcook.

Questions on Stack Overflow need to be:

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Decompressing a file is not a problem unique to software development. Lots of other contexts (de)compress files and as such it is considered a general computing activity, similar to finding files, using a text editor or installing a browser.

For sure decompressing files can be a programming task. That is when you're tasked with consuming a compressed file in Haskell or your other favorite programming language. But the focus is then on using a specific API or binding to achieve a specific programming goal. The question in question doesn't have any signs of that.

It is correctly closed and it should remain in that state. We don't need new answers to an off-topic question.

Comment: Stack Overcook? Poor [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com) :)

Comment: Good answer.  I didn't think about this perspective -- it's not specifically about programming (or associated tools).  I recall there was a big push a long time back to migrate questions to unix Q&A site.  Is this Q&A a good candidate for migration?

Comment: @kevinarpe if you had seen it earlier you could have close voted for migration. Earlier means < 60 days old. Once a question is older than 60 days, migration is no longer possible, not even by mods. Always keep in mind rule one of migration: [Don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225006/add-a-dont-migrate-crap-migration-path-to-all-sites). Second rule is: Only suggest migration to a site you're familiar with.

Comment: This isn't a situation where someone gave an answer about cooking though. Someone may have asked a question poorly, but the answers are good and do solve a specific programming task. The fact that both the question (despite being malformed) and the top answer both have over 200 upvotes is strong evidence that the answer was helpful to many people who did have that specific, programming-oriented problem.

Comment: @zfj3ub94rf576hc4eegm luckily then that it won't be easily deleted so lots of visitors can find those answers, assuming they arrive from Google on that Q/A pair. Only users that have an even better way to ---make coffee--- compress a file are out of luck and should go find the proper site to post their answer.